# What is a 'Lucky Monster'?

Tags: lost-ark

I have collected enough cards to be able to setup a bonus, however I've no idea what a Lucky Monster is.

> Pirate Generation - Damage +100% to Lucky Monsters.

[image: Pirate Generation - Damage +100% to Lucky Monsters.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are two types of lucky monster encounters.

You will obtain secret maps that look like treasure maps with what usually amounts to one big mob, and many small critters both are lucky monsters, and rarely if you are in a Chaos Dungeon, a golden portal will open. The monsters spawning on that stage are lucky too.

In total, this card bonus will help you out very rarely, and I'd recommend swapping to something else (or using it as a preset so you can quickly swap for those chance situations).